# Use programmatic navigation(Vue) with axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I want to use *programmatic navigation* with *axios*, but sometimes it doesn't work.

I solved this issue by using routing before using axios rather than in the `.then` statement, that I receive as a result of a post request.

I wonder why this (working in a `then`) is not working.
(*I think this is because of the Promise Object, but I'm not sure*)

Does anyone know what is the problem?

This is my code snippet of **FileUpload.vue**

```
<template>
  <b-button @click="submitFile">submit</b-button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      image: null
    }
  }
  methods: {
    submitFile(){
      // ... handle form data

      // use axios for backend API
      axios.post(http://localhost:8000/api/upload/', formData, {
       headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
      }).then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        this.$router.push({name: 'products'});  // not working!
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });    
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Have you debugged to see if you are hitting the then() vs the catch() callbacks?

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually has a few different issues.

First of all, you are missing an opening single quote in your POST url.
Second, you just have a few general syntax errors (provided the given example is your real code).

1. You need to have a comma between your data and methods definitions.
2. You are completely missing a closing curly brace on your submit method.

Your code should be corrected like so:

```
export default {  
    data() {  
        return {
            image: null  
        }  
    },  
    methods: {  
        submitFile() {  
            axios.post('http: //localhost:8000/api/upload/', formData,{
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                }
            })  
            .then((res) => {  
                console.log(res);  
                this.$router.push({  
                    name: 'products'  
                });  
            }).catch((err) => {  
                console.log(err);  
            });  
        }  
    }  
}
```